# mediaplayer gives me null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, media-player, volume, android-audiomanager

I want my code to play a sound file at MAX volume when a button is pressed.  My code works perfectly fine just playing the sound file, but when I throw in `originalVolume`

```
int originalVolume = mAudioManager
                        .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        mAudioManager
                                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
                        0);
```

My program crashes upon the click of the button.

```
public class VolumeUp extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    int counter = 0;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);

        text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int originalVolume = mAudioManager
                        .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        mAudioManager
                                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
                        0);

                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(VolumeUp.this,
                        R.raw.policesiren);
                mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);// we set the sound to loop.
                mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        originalVolume, 0);
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code you have shown above, mAudioManager is null all the time. So its obvious why you get NPE.

you forgot this line:

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```